# Error 403 when sending post to API route in PHP laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

I just learnt the basics of laravel for a school project and I lack a lot of technical experience regarding web development.

I'm trying to make an API to create a new user in the database, I have a group of routes (`/users`) as declared in the following code:

```php
Route::prefix('/users')
    ->controller(UserController::class)
    ->group(function() {
        Route::post('/', 'store');

        Route::prefix('/update')
            ->group(function() {
                Route::post('/password', 'updatePassword');
            });
    });
```

I'm using Postman to send a post request to `/api/users`. I'm getting `Forbiden error 403`.

[image: postman]

There is no middlware in use, I tried adding `accept application/json` to headers but got no results.

The `/api/users/update/password` is giving the same error.

What is causing this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: I figured it out, the authorize method in the request.php was returning false

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the autorize method in the request file was returning false, I changed it to true and everything is working

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

use App\Http\Requests\BaseRequest;

class UpdatePasswordRequest extends BaseRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
.
.
.
}
```